# Need to access field of a table which is defined by a condition

Tags: mysql

I need to access the field of a database table which is defined by a condition in a query.I need to access the SERVICE_LEG column and filter data from that column.

```
SELECT 
pa1.countryname,
pw.serviceprovideractorwid,
pa2.id,
pw.orderid,
pw.issorderref,
po.modelcode,
pw.itemid,
pe1.eventcode AS STARTEVENTCODE,
pe2.eventcode AS ENDEVENTCODE,
  CASE 
  WHEN pw.enddate < pof.retdate THEN 'TO_SERVICE'
  ELSE 'FROM SERVICE'
  END AS "SERVICE_LEG",
pa1.roleid,
pad.activitycode,
pw.tat,
pw.totelapse
FROM phwactivitydetail pw
JOIN phdactor pa1 ON pa1.actorwid = pw.orderissactorwid
JOIN phdactor pa2 ON pa2.actorwid = pw.serviceprovideractorwid
JOIN phdobject po ON po.objectwid = pw.objectwid
JOIN phdevent pe1 ON pe1.eventwid = pw.starteventwid
JOIN phdevent pe2 ON pe2.eventwid = pw.endeventwid
JOIN phaorderflowcatch pof ON pof.orderdid = pw.orderdid
JOIN phxactivitydef pad ON pad.activitydefdid = pw.activitydefdid
JOIN gldcalendar gc ON gc.datenum = pw.enddatenum;
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `outer sub-query` to achieve that.

## Demo:

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
(
    SELECT 
    pa1.countryname,
    pw.serviceprovideractorwid,
    pa2.id,
    pw.orderid,
    pw.issorderref,
    po.modelcode,
    pw.itemid,
    pe1.eventcode AS STARTEVENTCODE,
    pe2.eventcode AS ENDEVENTCODE,
      CASE 
      WHEN pw.enddate < pof.retdate THEN 'TO_SERVICE'
      ELSE 'FROM SERVICE'
      END AS "SERVICE_LEG",
    pa1.roleid,
    pad.activitycode,
    pw.tat,
    pw.totelapse
    FROM phwactivitydetail pw
    JOIN phdactor pa1 ON pa1.actorwid = pw.orderissactorwid
    JOIN phdactor pa2 ON pa2.actorwid = pw.serviceprovideractorwid
    JOIN phdobject po ON po.objectwid = pw.objectwid
    JOIN phdevent pe1 ON pe1.eventwid = pw.starteventwid
    JOIN phdevent pe2 ON pe2.eventwid = pw.endeventwid
    JOIN phaorderflowcatch pof ON pof.orderdid = pw.orderdid
    JOIN phxactivitydef pad ON pad.activitydefdid = pw.activitydefdid
    JOIN gldcalendar gc ON gc.datenum = pw.enddatenum
) t
WHERE t.SERVICE_LEG > 100;
```

Answer (score 0):

column name TO_SERVICE and FROM SERVICE should be enclosed by backtick "`" and not "'" as it will make it variable.

```
SELECT 
pa1.countryname,
pw.serviceprovideractorwid,
pa2.id,
pw.orderid,
pw.issorderref,
po.modelcode,
pw.itemid,
pe1.eventcode AS STARTEVENTCODE,
pe2.eventcode AS ENDEVENTCODE,
  CASE 
  WHEN pw.enddate < pof.retdate THEN `TO_SERVICE`
  ELSE `FROM SERVICE`
  END AS "SERVICE_LEG",
pa1.roleid,
pad.activitycode,
pw.tat,
pw.totelapse
FROM phwactivitydetail pw
JOIN phdactor pa1 ON pa1.actorwid = pw.orderissactorwid
JOIN phdactor pa2 ON pa2.actorwid = pw.serviceprovideractorwid
JOIN phdobject po ON po.objectwid = pw.objectwid
JOIN phdevent pe1 ON pe1.eventwid = pw.starteventwid
JOIN phdevent pe2 ON pe2.eventwid = pw.endeventwid
JOIN phaorderflowcatch pof ON pof.orderdid = pw.orderdid
JOIN phxactivitydef pad ON pad.activitydefdid = pw.activitydefdid
JOIN gldcalendar gc ON gc.datenum = pw.enddatenum;
```

Further you can add condition as per below-

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
    SELECT 
    pa1.countryname,
    pw.serviceprovideractorwid,
    pa2.id,
    pw.orderid,
    pw.issorderref,
    po.modelcode,
    pw.itemid,
    pe1.eventcode AS STARTEVENTCODE,
    pe2.eventcode AS ENDEVENTCODE,
      CASE 
      WHEN pw.enddate < pof.retdate THEN `TO_SERVICE`
      ELSE `FROM SERVICE`
      END AS "SERVICE_LEG",
    pa1.roleid,
    pad.activitycode,
    pw.tat,
    pw.totelapse
    FROM phwactivitydetail pw
    JOIN phdactor pa1 ON pa1.actorwid = pw.orderissactorwid
    JOIN phdactor pa2 ON pa2.actorwid = pw.serviceprovideractorwid
    JOIN phdobject po ON po.objectwid = pw.objectwid
    JOIN phdevent pe1 ON pe1.eventwid = pw.starteventwid
    JOIN phdevent pe2 ON pe2.eventwid = pw.endeventwid
    JOIN phaorderflowcatch pof ON pof.orderdid = pw.orderdid
    JOIN phxactivitydef pad ON pad.activitydefdid = pw.activitydefdid
    JOIN gldcalendar gc ON gc.datenum = pw.enddatenum
) a
where a.SERVICE_LEG="put_condition_here"
;
```

Comment: Ok It can access like this. If I need to access that SERVICE_LEG on the WHERE clause in this table. Not out of the table. After the last join statement...

Answer (score 0):

You can use a common table expression, for example.

```
WITH CTE(countryname,serviceprovideractorwid,id ...., SERVICE_LEG,... )
AS
(
SELECT 
pa1.countryname,
pw.serviceprovideractorwid,
pa2.id,
...
  CASE 
  WHEN pw.enddate < pof.retdate THEN 'TO_SERVICE'
  ELSE 'FROM SERVICE'
  END AS "SERVICE_LEG",
...
FROM phwactivitydetail pw
JOIN phdactor pa1 ON pa1.actorwid = pw.orderissactorwid
JOIN phdactor pa2 ON pa2.actorwid = pw.serviceprovideractorwid
JOIN phdobject po ON po.objectwid = pw.objectwid
JOIN phdevent pe1 ON pe1.eventwid = pw.starteventwid
JOIN phdevent pe2 ON pe2.eventwid = pw.endeventwid
JOIN phaorderflowcatch pof ON pof.orderdid = pw.orderdid
JOIN phxactivitydef pad ON pad.activitydefdid = pw.activitydefdid
JOIN gldcalendar gc ON gc.datenum = pw.enddatenum  )
SELECT * 
FROM CTE
WHERE SERVICE_LEG = "your_condition"
```